# Drill down into nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

This is a very noob question so please forgive me.

Please can someone help me drill down into a nested dictionary.

I'd like to know how to access the dictionary "data"  (see data in link) so that I can then analyze it.

Many thanks in advance.

[My sample data is here:](https://github.com/mwoolgar/Miles-Github/blob/master/small_data_clean.json)

I'm using jupyter notbooks.

This is what I have so far:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('./source/small_data_clean.json') as access_json:
    read_content = json.load(access_json)


type(read_content)

data_access = read_content['data']
data_access
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to just keep accessing the keys in each level:

For example:

```
data_access['data']
data_access['data']['0']
data_access['data']['0']['Pi']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iteratively access the elements in the dict, here is a working example;

```
# TODO: Access, "data" -> "0" -> "Vi" -> "Diff"

def index_nested_dict(dict: dict, keys: list):
    for key in keys:
        dict = dict[key]

    return dict

test_dict = {
    "total": 1498,
    "state": "0",
    "limit": 10,
    "offset": 0,
    "data": {
        "0": {
            "Pi": "18165592935938996736",
            "Ph": "keyword 1",
            "Kb": 20190326,
            "Tg": {},
            "Cp": "2.25",
            "Nq": "260",
            "Gs": "0",
            "Dt": {
                "20191225": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": 7
                }
            },
            "Be": {
                "*.mysite.com\/*": 7
            },
            "Fi": {
                "*.mysite.com\/*": 7
            },
            "Diff": {
                "*.mysite.com\/*": 0
            },
            "Diff1": {
                "*.mysite.com\/*": 93
            },
            "Diff7": {
                "*.mysite.com\/*": 93
            },
            "Diff30": {
                "*.mysite.com\/*": 93
            },
            "Vi": {
                "20191225": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": 0.0068999999999999999
                },
                "Diff": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": 0
                }
            },
            "Sf": {
                "20191225": [
                    "adt",
                    "rev",
                    "stl"
                ]
            },
            "Tr": {
                "20191225": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": 0.32000000000000001
                }
            },
            "Tc": {
                "20191225": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": 0.73999999999999999
                }
            },
            "Lu": {
                "20191225": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": "https:\/\/www.mysite.com\/product.cfm?p=155"
                }
            },
            "Lt": {
                "20191225": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": [
                        "org"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "1": {
            "Pi": "1090615528833642752",
            "Ph": "keyword 2",
            "Kb": 20190326,
            "Tg": {},
            "Cp": "0.81",
            "Nq": "390",
            "Gs": "0",
            "Dt": {
                "20191225": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": 3
                }
            },
            "Be": {
                "*.mysite.com\/*": 3
            },
            "Fi": {
                "*.mysite.com\/*": 3
            },
            "Diff": {
                "*.mysite.com\/*": 0
            },
            "Diff1": {
                "*.mysite.com\/*": 97
            },
            "Diff7": {
                "*.mysite.com\/*": 97
            },
            "Diff30": {
                "*.mysite.com\/*": 97
            },
            "Vi": {
                "20191225": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": 0.017399999999999999
                },
                "Diff": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": 0
                }
            },
            "Sf": {
                "20191225": [
                    "adb"
                ]
            },
            "Tr": {
                "20191225": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": 1.23
                }
            },
            "Tc": {
                "20191225": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": 1
                }
            },
            "Lu": {
                "20191225": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": "https:\/\/www.mysite.com\/keyword2\/"
                }
            },
            "Lt": {
                "20191225": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": [
                        "org"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "Pi": "13621862969727492608",
            "Ph": "keyword 3",
            "Kb": 20190326,
            "Tg": {},
            "Cp": "0.52",
            "Nq": "210",
            "Gs": "0",
            "Dt": {
                "20191225": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": 25
                }
            },
            "Be": {
                "*.mysite.com\/*": 25
            },
            "Fi": {
                "*.mysite.com\/*": 25
            },
            "Diff": {
                "*.mysite.com\/*": 0
            },
            "Diff1": {
                "*.mysite.com\/*": 75
            },
            "Diff7": {
                "*.mysite.com\/*": 75
            },
            "Diff30": {
                "*.mysite.com\/*": 75
            },
            "Vi": {
                "20191225": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": 0.0016000000000000001
                },
                "Diff": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": 0
                }
            },
            "Sf": {
                "20191225": [
                    "stl"
                ]
            },
            "Tr": {
                "20191225": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": 0.059999999999999998
                }
            },
            "Tc": {
                "20191225": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": 0.029999999999999999
                }
            },
            "Lu": {
                "20191225": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": "https:\/\/www.mysite.com\/keyword3\/"
                }
            },
            "Lt": {
                "20191225": {
                    "*.mysite.com\/*": [
                        "org"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
},
"Sfc": {
    "org": {
        "Ex": 0,
        "Ne": 1498,
        "De": 0,
        "Dn": 0
    },
    "geo": {
        "Ex": 7,
        "Ne": 1491,
        "De": 0,
        "Dn": 7
    },
    "amp": {
        "Ex": 0,
        "Ne": 1498,
        "De": 0,
        "Dn": 0
    },
    "tea": {
        "Ex": 0,
        "Ne": 1498,
        "De": 0,
        "Dn": 0
    },
    "new": {
        "Ex": 4,
        "Ne": 1494,
        "De": 0,
        "Dn": 4
    },
    "rel": {
        "Ex": 56,
        "Ne": 1442,
        "De": 0,
        "Dn": 56
    },
    "img": {
        "Ex": 2,
        "Ne": 1496,
        "De": 0,
        "Dn": 2
    },
    "adt": {
        "Ex": 275,
        "Ne": 1223,
        "De": 82,
        "Dn": 193
    },
    "shp": {
        "Ex": 103,
        "Ne": 1395,
        "De": 0,
        "Dn": 103
    },
    "knw": {
        "Ex": 1,
        "Ne": 1497,
        "De": 0,
        "Dn": 1
    },
    "twt": {
        "Ex": 0,
        "Ne": 1498,
        "De": 0,
        "Dn": 0
    },
    "app": {
        "Ex": 0,
        "Ne": 1498,
        "De": 0,
        "Dn": 0
    },
    "vib": {
        "Ex": 0,
        "Ne": 1498,
        "De": 0,
        "Dn": 0
    },
    "rev": {
        "Ex": 1208,
        "Ne": 290,
        "De": 0,
        "Dn": 1208
    },
    "vid": {
        "Ex": 6,
        "Ne": 1492,
        "De": 0,
        "Dn": 6
    },
    "fsn": {
        "Ex": 67,
        "Ne": 1431,
        "De": 0,
        "Dn": 67
    },
    "stl": {
        "Ex": 911,
        "Ne": 587,
        "De": 69,
        "Dn": 842
    },
    "adb": {
        "Ex": 573,
        "Ne": 925,
        "De": 220,
        "Dn": 353
    },
    "kng": {
        "Ex": 32,
        "Ne": 1466,
        "De": 0,
        "Dn": 32
    }
},
"Vc": {
    "0-10": 199,
    "11 - 100": 36,
    "101 - 1000": 1006,
    "1001 - 10000": 204,
    "10001+": 53
},
"Topc": {
    "all": 1498,
    "all_improved": 0,
    "all_declined": 0,
    "all_difference": 0,
    "all_left": 0,
    "all_entered": 0,
    "all_unchanged": 1498,
    "top3": 177,
    "top3_improved": 0,
    "top3_declined": 0,
    "top3_difference": 0,
    "top3_left": 0,
    "top3_entered": 0,
    "top3_unchanged": 177,
    "top10": 512,
    "top10_improved": 0,
    "top10_declined": 0,
    "top10_difference": 0,
    "top10_left": 0,
    "top10_entered": 0,
    "top10_unchanged": 512,
    "top20": 741,
    "top20_improved": 0,
    "top20_declined": 0,
    "top20_difference": 0,
    "top20_left": 0,
    "top20_entered": 0,
    "top20_unchanged": 741,
    "4_10": 335,
    "4_10_improved": 0,
    "4_10_declined": 0,
    "4_10_difference": 0,
    "4_10_left": 0,
    "4_10_entered": 0,
    "4_10_unchanged": 335,
    "11_20": 229,
    "11_20_improved": 0,
    "11_20_declined": 0,
    "11_20_difference": 0,
    "11_20_left": 0,
    "11_20_entered": 0,
    "11_20_unchanged": 229,
    "21_100": 694,
    "21_100_improved": 0,
    "21_100_declined": 0,
    "21_100_difference": 0,
    "21_100_left": 0,
    "21_100_entered": 0,
    "21_100_unchanged": 694,
    "top100": 1435,
    "top100_improved": 0,
    "top100_declined": 0,
    "top100_difference": 0,
    "top100_left": 0,
    "top100_entered": 0,
    "top100_unchanged": 1435,
    "out": 63,
    "out_improved": 0,
    "out_declined": 0,
    "out_difference": 0,
    "out_left": 0,
    "out_entered": 0,
    "out_unchanged": 63
},
"server": "USA",
"exec_time": 2.705991
}

print(index_nested_dict(test_dict, ["data", "0", "Vi", "Diff"]))
```

prints {'*.mysite.com\/*': 0}

Comment: Thanks Vinzent. You are right but I gave the answer to the first one because he was the first to answer. I would also like to give you cudos as well. Sorry I can't also give you a tick :(